# toggle open and stay open multiple div

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have searching last 4 days to find a working solution for toggle menu. So far i found was that close open div when click another div. Also checked many question in Stackoverflow but none of them was worked as i wanted.
What i want to do is that click div (parent) and open (child) click parent again and close child.
How i can i do that for multiple parents.

my page structure something like:

```
DIV PARENT
   div child
DIV PARENT
   div child
DIV PARENT
   div child
```

.... and so on
This is my jquery implementation
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js

This is my php code

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < count($job_id); $i++)
    {
        $bg = ($i % 2) ? "odd" : "even";

        echo '
        <div class="block">
            <div style="border:solid 1px;" id="parent" class="parent ' .$bg. '">
                <div style="float:left; width:50%;"><div class="myMsGothic">' .$title[$i]. '</div></div>
                <div style="float:left; width:15%;">' .$name[$i]. '</div>
                <div style="float:left; width:15%;">' .$area[$i]. '</div>
                <div style="float:left; width:20%; text-align:right;" class="myMsMincho">ID　：　' .strtoupper($_id[$i]). '</div>
                <div class="clearLeft"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="child"><div class="innerContents"><p>' .nl2br($description[$i]). '</p></div></div>
        </div>';
    }
?>
```

Unfortunately i have no js script in my page now because none of them i was tried worked

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Please include any markup and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.parent').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.child').toggle();
});
```

If you don't like `toggle()`, you can also try the fancier `slideToggle()` and `fadeToggle()`.

You mentioned you only want to show parents on page load. Just add these:

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.parent').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/my5C9/1/

Comment: dear Marlo. Thanks for answer but nothing changed. child div doesn't open actually it is already open :(

Comment: Close them first in your css by adding .child { display: none;}

Comment: @yener Sorry, I didn't know you wanted it closed by default. Follow Jay's suggestion and it should work.

Comment: i can't believe your code is working on jsfiddle but same code is not working on my page. Another point is that i want to show parents only when page load

Comment: @yener Include all your HTML and script code on your post so we can all see it. I edited my answer to address your last request.

Comment: Are you including Jquery??

Comment: Dear Robert, yes i include jquery <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: i removed my css files, any other js files but nothing changed but still not working.

Comment: @yener Check this fiddle. I simplified what you made so you can see it. http://jsfiddle.net/J7QSB/7/

Comment: Dear Marlo. thank you so much for your effort. Finally i made it work with your help. However, all boxes are open by default. How can i close all of them on page load. Thank you much for your help again.

Comment: @yener Glad I could help you figure it out yourself, and that's what's important! You can set .child css to "display:none" :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple solution. Boxes closed by default. Click to open/close multiple toggles.

The HTML Markup

```
<div class="toggle">See Stuff</div>
<div class="paragraph">
<p>Content</p>
<p>Video</p>
<p>Image</p>
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>
<a href="#">Links</a>
</div>
```

The jQuery

```
<script>
$('.paragraph').hide();
$('.toggle').click(function() {
var panel = $(this).next()
$('.paragraph').not(panel).slideUp();
panel.slideToggle({
    direction: "down"
}, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Style It

```
<style>    
.toggle{margin-bottom:25px; margin-top:25px; margin-left:10px; padding:10px; 
font-size:24px; color:#2554C7; cursor: pointer;}
.paragraph{clear:both;margin-top:25px;}
</style>
```